# how to access family details from facebook using fbconnect in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, fbconnect

in my new application i want to access family members from facebook including members photos. am accessing users details such as name and photos.

I am using the permission to access data from facebook is shown below

```
mPermission =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream", @"publish_stream", @"offline_access",@"email",@"publish_checkins",@"manage_notifications",@"friends_photos",@"user_photos",nil];
    mFacebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:self];      

NSMutableDictionary * paramss = 

[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user  AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())",@"query",nil];

[mFacebook requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"
                       andParams:paramss
                   andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                     andDelegate:self];
```

How can i get family details ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has a detailed explanation about how to query for a user's family. Check [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/family) to read all about it.

They require you to have the additional permission called 'user_relationships'. Then you can query the family table. It provides the family member's name, birthday and relationship status.

For the profile picture you must (if I'm correct) fetch these from the user table using the UID from the family member, should be possible with a join. Look for the columns that start with 'pic'.

Comment: SELECT profile_id, relationship FROM family WHERE profile_id = <uid>
how to put uid in this fql i got error  NSMutableDictionary * params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"SELECT  name,relationship,uid FROM family WHERE profile_id IN (SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid = me())", @"query",
                                    nil];
    [mFacebook requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"
                           andParams:params1
                       andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                         andDelegate:self];

Comment: I gave the docs of the Facebook iOS SDK a quick look and found a way to perform a multi-query which you can use. Read the section at step 2b called multi-query [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/run-fql-queries-ios-sdk).

Comment: When using this query SELECT profile_id, relationship FROM family WHERE profile_id = me() I got nothing ..